# Google Keyboard Esperanto Dictionary

Tags: keyboard, swype, dictionary, gboard

## My goal

To have Google Keyboard predict Esperanto words.

## Current Status

As of posting date, I am using the most updated Google Keyboard app, on Android L.

The Esperanto keyboard is present and enabled, but it does not suggest or correct words. There is a personal Esperanto dictionary, but the personal dictionary is empty of words and no Esperanto dictionary is available in the addons menu, even after refreshing.

### Possible Resolutions

According [to posts on Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/8841170) in early 2015, Google Keyboard used to support an Esperanto dictionary. It is possible that I have not performed the necessary steps to have this dictionary available on my device. Enabling a Google-supported Esperanto dictionary would be ideal.

If the Esperanto dictionary has been deprecated or is otherwise not available, I would like to be able to add an Esperanto word list to my personal dictionary. However I do not see how to add more than one word at a time.

Comment: Have you tried `Settings - Language and input - Google keyboard - Languages - Turn off Use system language and turn on Esperanto` ?

Comment: Yes. The Esperanto keyboard is active. It's just that the dictionary is empty.

Comment: Personal dictionary is the one which you add words to it manually. So it will be empty.

Comment: Yep. I think we're on the same page.

Comment: Can you reproduce this state, or does the Esperanto keyboard have a populated (non-personal) dictionary by default for you?

Comment: I've tried it and the suggestions didn't work for me either. It gives me some unrelated word suggestions in English. It's just that the Esperanto's Keyboard has some special letters included.

Comment: That mirrors my own observations. Thank you for the repro.